# is it possible to App Store in app subscription with local cards?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store, payment, in-app-subscription

we're going to integrate in-app-subscription to our current app. So there will be only one plan, and users pay for using our app(let's say features).

What i know is that App Store will get **30%** of revenue for in-app purchases. Even though, we agree with it, our users don't have **credit or debit cards**(to use).

They mostly use local cards or payment systems. which is not supported by Apple. Apple **don't allow third party payments**.

in this situation, how can we add subscription module to our app? is there any way to do it in "Apple way"?